# MySQL Question - Find the title and year of each movie that someone rated with 5 stars and someone else rated with fewer than 3 stars

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, where-clause

I am provided three tables, one called Person which has an id (primary key) and name attribute, a Movie table with title, year (where title and year together are the primary key) and finally a Saw table which connects the two previous tables and has primary keys, id, title, year, and attribute numStars (rating person gave movie).

So to recap:

**Person table:**

*id*

name

**Movie table:**

*title*

*year*

**Saw table:**

*id*

*title*

*year*

numStars

I'm confused about how to accomplish finding a movie with both a 5 star user rating and a less than 3 star user rating. I'm supposed to do this with both WHERE IN and with a join. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you relate `person` and `saw`? Also, doesn't `movie` has a primary key, like `movie(id)`?

Comment: Person and Saw are related by id and movie's primary key is the combination of title and year. And Movie is related to saw by title and year together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select 
    m.title,
    m.year
from movie m
inner join saw s 
    on s.title = m.title
    and s.year = m.year
group by m.title, m.year
having 
having 
    sum(numStars = 5) >= 1 
    and sum(numStars < 3) >= 1
```

Another option, which avoids the use of aggregation, is to use two `exists` condition with correlated subqueries:

```
select 
    m.title,
    m.year
from movie m
where
    exists (
        select 1 
        from saw s 
        where 
            s.title = m.title 
            and s.year = m.year
            and s.numStars = 5
    )
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from saw s 
        where 
            s.title = m.title 
            and s.year = m.year
            and s.numStars < 3
    )
```

Comment: What does the id end part do? Also, just a minor thing, should be <3, not =3.

Comment: @DesperateCoder: I simplified the query, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah I see. I believe this works thank you so much. If it's no bother, do you happen to know a way to do this without using "having?" Using WHERE... IN for instance

Comment: @DesperateCoder: welcome! I updated my answer with a solution without aggregation.